# Cannot append list to a list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I can't find this question elsewhere on StackOverflow, or maybe my researching skills are not advanced enough, so I am asking now:

So I was playing around with Python today after not having touched it in a while and I found that the following snippet of code does not work:

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3]
>>> list2 = [4,5,6]
>>> list3 = list1.append(list2)
>>> list3
```

Why does the last line not produce any results?

Also, I'm using Python 2.7.3, if that makes any difference

Comment: Looks like you want `list3 = list1 + list2`

Comment: I agree with @JonClements -- Another option if you want to modify `list1` *in-place* then you can use `extend`:  `list1.extend(list2)`.  The benefit here is that `list2` doesn't have to be a list -- anything iterable will do.  The downside is that you've just changed `list1`

Comment: There are literally dozens of questions about how to concatenate lists.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`list.append()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable) operates *in-place* - it modifies the list it is called upon, and returns `None`.

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3]
>>> list2 = [4,5,6]
>>> list1.append(list2)
>>> list1
[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]
```

So when you assign the returned value to `list3`, `list3` is `None`, which the interactive shell does not print out implicitly like other results.

As a note, you might actually want `list.extend()` or `+`, depending on your use case.

Answer (score 5):

`list1.append(list2)` modifies `list1` and returns `None`, so `list3` is `None`. `None` is not printed in interactive mode when it is the result of a statement.

Answer (score 5):

In addition, in order to concatenate the lists you can do:

```
list3 = list1 + list2
```